# Angular2 how to send queryParams to the url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've this url *www.mydomain.com/login*

How can I insert a link in this page to go to *www.mydomain.com/login?type=password*?

I've tried

```
<a href="?type=password">Recover Password</a>
```

But it refreshes the page as expected. How I would do this?

Comment: Please read the this link. It'll make you familiar with with server interactions. 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: Thank you guys! Those resources have helped!